What do these two symmetrical hooks on this captain's helmet do?
In the movie 1917, in the final dashing scene, there is a captain who is crying and cannot say a word.
The crying captain wears a helmet that is not like any other in the British army, it looks like this:

What are the two hooks on the right and left side of the top of the rim for?

It seems the hooks are for attaching the metal straps of the 'Cruise visor', a rectangular piece of chain mail to protect the eyes:








source
More information about the Cruise visor:

Designed by Captain Richard C. Cruise, R.A.M.C. (T); Surgeon-Occulist Extraordinary to the King, and manufactured in large numbers [during the period of] 1916-1917, to limit the amount of preventable blindness and injuries to the eyes caused by small particles of metal, stone, rock, brick, wood or sand. Eye injuries were particularly frequent in the mountain fighting o[n] the Italo-Austrian Front. The vizor of closely woven links was worn taut, touching the tip of the nose, and was adjusted by attaching a chain to a movable loop on the helmet chin-strap. The vizor could also be adjusted in such a way as to leave the aiming eye free.
source

Where the visor of the captain in your picture is, I do not know, but I can imagine it having been removed for a plethora of practical reasons.

wow, I would imagine a crusader kinight wearing something like this, not a WWI British soldier.

@YuZhang While it looks dated, it’s essentially the best that was possible for this purpose at the time. Glass would have shattered too easily, and transparent polymers would have been too expensive at the time to be practical. Even today there are a number of cases where chainmail is unarguably the best option, though it’s increasingly less common as time goes on.

Out of world, anything that hides the actor's face is often removed or minimised.  A large part of acting is in the face.

Many soldiers during WW1 got disfigured by shrapnels ("broken faces" in France were given priority seats in public transportation in France for a long time in France.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gueules_cass%C3%A9es (warning: images may be shocking for some)). And I would imagine that the flexibility of the chainmail would be efficient in dissipating the energy of a projectile (like a ball is stopped by a curtain), while a solid object may break or be transpierced.

When the only protection provided for your face against ballistics is a loosely hanging chain mail curtain... you know you're in for a bad time. The least they could've done is added a lower structure in the jaw area so the chain mail could be attached and made taut. Maybe with a strip leading down to protect the bridge of the nose as well... It reveals how expendable the troops were regarded to be. In contrast (although heavy) Samurai kabuto offered much better facial coverage, even as early as the late 1500s.

@Mentalist: Eh, even dissipating a projectile's force over a larger area can be valuable. There's a reason why silk vests were worn as low-cost protections against bullets. The impact gets at least partially dissipate if the projectile can't penetrate the medium. It turns penetrating trauma into blunt trauma, and increases the chance that the projectile can be dug out, since the material gets embedded behind it. The flexibility is actually a bit of a bonus because the projectile gets slowed for a longer period of time, versus a hard/taut surface, which will break.

@Mentalist A modern 9 mm bullet has about 700 J of energy leaving the gun. A boxer's punch is 700-1000 J. The difference is the area the energy is applied to. Another example: smack your desk. Then put an awl or screwdriver between your hand and your desk. The latter will cause far more damage.
